# Setting disabled on custom reactive form control results in Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: angular, custom-controls, angular-reactive-forms

I built a custom input control in my Angular project. It all works well, except when I set the disabled attribute to true, then some infinite loop occurs on setDisabledState leading to a

```
preview-4adb70f742b91f09679fb.js:1 ERROR RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
    at eval (model.ts:1519)
    at eval (model.ts:1531)
    at eval (model.ts:1493)
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at FormGroup._forEachChild (model.ts:1493)
    at FormGroup._reduceChildren (model.ts:1530)
    at FormGroup._reduceValue (model.ts:1518)
    at FormGroup._updateValue (model.ts:1505)
    at FormGroup.AbstractControl.updateValueAndValidity (model.ts:575)
    at FormControl.AbstractControl._updateAncestors (model.ts:533)
```

I created a Stackblitz showing the problem: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-n34zrj

Am I missing something with respect to setting the disabled property of the internal FormControl (using diabled(), enabled())?

If so, please let me know how to tackle this. Bashing my head over it for hours.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your code you force a loop by setting the disabled state depending on the boolean setDisabledState() param. And inside this method you call disable() / enable() which will call setDisabledState() themselves.

```
  setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    isDisabled ? this.control.disable() : this.control.enable();
  }
```

https://netbasal.com/angular-custom-form-controls-made-easy-4f963341c8e2

try something like Netanel Basal does:

```
  setDisabledState( isDisabled : boolean ) : void {
    const div = this.textarea.nativeElement;
    const action = isDisabled ? 'addClass' : 'removeClass';
    this.renderer[action](div, 'disabled');
  }
```

Comment: Thanks, I think I tackled it now. I also looked at https://medium.com/@vadimkorr/implementing-nested-custom-controls-in-angular-5-c115c68e6b88. The updated stackblitz now does not show any error.

Answer (score 4):

if you have the error using something like stated in Severin Klugs answer fixed by stopping unnecessary calls but checking if they are the same before applying the function

```
setDisabledState?(isDisabled: boolean): void {
    if(isDisabled == this.control.disabled) return;
    isDisabled ? this.control.disable() : this.control.enable();
}
```